# Meteor - Wait until collection is fully ready

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have this function in collection **Services** which returns services that has certain statuses.

```
_.extend(Services, {
    getServiceTypes: function () {
        return [
            { _id: '', serviceType: '' },
            { _id: 'Plumbing', serviceType: 'Plumbing' },
            { _id: 'Electrical', serviceType: 'Electrical' },
            { _id: 'HVAC', serviceType: 'HVAC' }
        ];
    },
    whereStatus: function (name) {
        let status = Statuses.findOne({ name: name });
        return this.find({ statusId: status._id });
    },
    whereServiceType: function (serviceType) {
        return Services.find({ serviceType: serviceType });
    }
});
```

whereServiceTypes() works but whereStatus() does not. This is because  the variable status is undefined initally and then it has some value. I want it to wait until status has the value returned from the Mongo collection and then proceed ahead.

BTW, I want to chain these functions like so.. `Services.whereStatus('Completed').whereServiceType('HVAC').fetch()`, is that possible?

Comment: Shouldn't you use a subscription for what you want? With a subscription you can wait for it to be ready...

Comment: I think that it's unrelated to subscription because I added autopublish and insecure and the problem still occured.

Comment: The issue you are describing sounds a lot like waiting for data to be ready, so if you create a publish function that handles the Statuses.findOne or w/e and then subscribe to it and wait for the result, seems like that should work

Comment: Even with autopublish it takes some time for collections to fully load. Do you really want that code to _block_ until the data is ready?

Comment: Yes, how do I do that? Because it runs multiple times. First time, it's undefined, and then it is defined.